# Best practice for passing large parameter data to a REST call

Tags: rest, http-headers

I have a REST Service that allows user to pass in a list of Properties they want returned from the call, eg:

```
/Item/123/Properties/Name,Id,Description,Type
```

There are hundreds of Property names that can be passed in, which then causes the issue that the number of chars supported between segments (eg: /IamASegment/) is 260 without changes to the registry etc.

So my question is when I need to support the user passing in large amounts of data like this, what is the best method, should it be passed in via the header?

Answer (score 0):

A proper REST solution would be to create a *form* on the previous page/state and submit that form via `POST`, which in turn would generate a redirected `GET` to the actual parameterized resource. The parameter in this case could be some number for example that represents a bit-field for the requested fields.

Something like this:

```
GET /items
{"form": {
   "Id": { "type": "number" },
   "Name" : { "type": "checkbox" },
   "Description" : { "type": "checkbox" },
   ...
}

POST /items
{"Name": "true", "Description": "true", ... }
```

Redirects to:

```
GET /items/123?fields=110110111
```

Of course you would have to define the proper `media-types` for the forms, requests, responses, etc.

Comment: I can see a couple of issues in my case with this solution, firstly the number of Properties available on the items we deal with far exceed 260, therefore the idea of passing back the 1s and 0s will fall into the same issue of the 260 limit.  Also as our product evolves we add more Properties to items, this would need continued maintenance of the code behind that decodes the 1s and 0s, our current back-end will just accept a call of Property = Name as a query.

Comment: You can of course code the bits as true bits, you can get 6 bits in one character easily, 260 bits is then 44 characters. The coding is completely transparent to the client, so you can control it on the server without updating the client. It can even be dynamic, you just have to remember/store/calculate which field is which bit.

Comment: That still leaves the issue of working out which field is which, that's extra code to maintain and would not be scalable even if it is an elegant solution.